# How to remove common nodes from XML files based on same attributes of input XML request using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XMLs:

**XML1.xml** which will be as an input request.

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v1</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen6">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v61</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

**XML2.xml** which will be stored xml file.

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v5</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen6">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v6</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen7">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
</service>
<service uri="/gen8">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

**Output** which i need is to get all the elements of **XML2.xml** except for the element having same **service** attribute in **XML1.xml**.

**Desired Output:**

```
<ConnectorConfig>
    <service uri="/gen7">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen8">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

This is what i tried.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConnectorConfig">
  <xsl:copy> 
     <xsl:variable name="item" select="document('XML2.xml')/ConnectorConfig"/>  
     <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/> 

   <xsl:for-each select="$item/service"> 
      <xsl:variable name="savedUri" select="@uri"/> 
 
        <xsl:if test="$current/service[@uri!=$savedUri]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:if> 

   </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output which i got for input request **XML1.xml** is :

```
<ConnectorConfig>
    <service uri="/gen5">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v5</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen6">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v6</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen7">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen8">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

But when i tried for same implementation with input **XML1a.xml** as:

```
<ConnectorConfig>
<service uri="/gen5">
<routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v1</routeUrl>
</service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

I received desired output which is shown below.

```
<ConnectorConfig>
    <service uri="/gen6">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v6</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen7">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
    <service uri="/gen8">
        <routeUrl>http://localhost:3003/v7</routeUrl>
    </service>
</ConnectorConfig>
```

In above, the output result contains all the elements of XML2.xml except one having **/gen5** as common attribute for service element in input **XML1a.xml**.

From the above what i came to known is that for single **service** element in input request, i'm getting the desired result but for multiple elements its fails.

What is the mistake i'm doing?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="ConnectorConfig">
    <xsl:variable name="local-uris" select="service/@uri" />
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('XML2.xml')/ConnectorConfig/service[not(@uri=$local-uris)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the predicate:

```
[not(@uri=$local-uris)]
```

is **not** the same as:

```
[@uri!=$local-uris]
```

The former passes only nodes whose `uri` does not have a matching value in `$local-uris`.

The latter passes any node whose `uri` is not equal to at least one `uri` in `$local-uris`.  In the given example, **all** nodes pass this test. If you reduce `$local-uris` to a single value, then all nodes will pass this test except the one that is equal to the single value. This should explain your own observations.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you.